# Embedding a zoom box in an SVG image

Tags: svg, hover, zooming

I'd like to make my SVG images interactive, with a zoom box that can be moved around by hovering or clicking the mouse in certain areas. Can this be done in a single SVG file, so that I can embed this interactive SVG image in a pdf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean like this? [Zoom and Pan](https://jwatt.org/svg/tests/zoom-and-pan-controls.svg)

Comment: It works in Firefox and Opera perhaps you should raise a bug on Webkit if Chrome does something different to those browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the link. The SVG code looks about as simple as it can get, and looks a great starting point. So ECMAScript would hopefully have an onhover and onmove events, and also access to cursor position variables. Ta